# Neo4jRepository on save adding multiple relationships

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Hello I am beginner to neo4j and using Spring Data Neo4j to create relations follows_on_uala on the outgoing direction between NodeProfile model.
If a person is already attempting same action it should not be allowed and just be logged. The use case works if i am creating 1 relationship i.e `A -- follow -- B`  but I see that duplicate relationship are added whenever I try to make a reverse relation `(b--follows-A)`. The same thing happens when I try to add 3rd to the mix. I require only 1 unique relation between nodes.
[This is what I get when 3rd node is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imdLM.png)

Here is my ProfileNode Model

```
import java.util.Set;
@Getter
@Setter
@Node("Profile")
public class ProfileNode {

    /*
    *   ProfileNode is the node that represents a user profile
    */

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String userId;
    private String displayName;

    public ProfileNode() {
    }

    public ProfileNode(String userId , String displayName) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    @Relationship(type = "FOLLOW_ON_UALA", direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    public Set<ProfileNode> followsOnUala;

    public void addUalaFollow(ProfileNode person) {
        if (followsOnUala == null) {
            followsOnUala = new HashSet<>();
        }
        followsOnUala.add(person);
    }
}
```

Here is how I am trying to save relation using Neo4J repository

```
    public void addUalaFollow(ProfileNode user, ProfileNode followHim) {
        if(user.getFollowsOnUala().contains(followHim)) {
            log.info("Follow Relation Exist");
        } else {
            user.addUalaFollow(followHim);
            repo.save(user);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you loaded `followHim` with its relationships, you have to check also the other direction for existence. In general, you should take care that you implement `equals()/hashCode()` in `ProfileNode` correct for you use-case.
Otherwise the check will be based on `Object` equality.

```java
followHim.getFollowsOnUala().contains(user)
```

Also adding a followed by `Direction.INCOMING` relationship definition with the same type might be helpful, if you want to traverse in both direction.
Usually I do not advice to create bidirectional relationships everywhere but in this case it would make sense.
But still the check would be needed to into the right branch of your condition.

Comment: Thanks for response !
i did override the hashcode and equal functions, Here is my hashCode. Somehow whenever I add reverse relation it also adds to the previous relation. 
`
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37)
                .append(this.id)
                .append(this.displayName)
                .append(this.userId)
                .append(this.followsOnUala)
                .toHashCode();
    }
`